# Only allow listing of specific mount points in Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a Vault instance with MySQL Database engines created under specific paths, like so:

```
mysql/dev/my-instance-1
mysql/staging/my-instance-2
mysql/prod/my-instance-3
```

now I allow users to list secrets via `vault secrets list` with following policy:

```
path "sys/mounts" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

This policy is now a bit top permissive for my needs, because the user then can list all `mysql/*` secrets, but I only want to allow listing for example `mysql/dev/*`.

I already tried some policies like:

```
path "sys/mounts/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}

path "mysql/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}
```

but nothing of that worked.